# Google Cloud SQL sharding

Tags: mysql, cloud, innodb, google-cloud-sql

I am now trying to use Google Cloud SQL as a solution for my project. However, I found no way to scale writing there. It uses innoDB, so I can't use features of NDB cluster. So I wanted to make some sharding, however I am unable to find any information about this. Are there any ways to scale writes to Google Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 0):

A single `INSERT` statement with 100 row will run 10 times as fast as 100 single-row `INSERTs`.

`LOAD DATA` is probably the fastest way to do inserts.

In some situations it can be faster to use a staging table - put the rows to insert in it, then copy to the 'real' table(s).

Please give more details about the data flow, the table schema, and scale (eg, rows/second).

Comment: Hello, Rick!
Data flow and schema dont matter. I'm speaking about scaling, what means that one instance of Cloud SQL can handle N connections. What shall I do when I need to handle 2*N connections? If these connections are read-only, I can use read replicas. However, what if I need 2*N writable connections? I see no way to handle it in Cloud SQL.  [Here](http://www.slideshare.net/mkindahl/mysql-sharding-tools-and-best-practices-for-horizontal-scaling) this problem is nicely described. Offered solution is mysqlfabric, but I can't use it on Google Cloud SQL

Comment: I think Fabric is dead.  It had a fatal flaw in the HA area.  It is being replaced by "InnoDB Cluster", which sounds quite viable.  Meanwhile, write-scaling:  Galera--up to about 3x; Sharding--unlimited write scaling.  I know nothing about Google Cloud; perhaps they have a good solution.

Comment: Write sharding implies that you will quickly have billions of rows.  But what will you do with all those rows?  This is a serious question -- often the answer to write-scaling is to eliminate the _need_ for it.  Hence, my request for more info.  Example:  Summarize the data into tables, store raw data in flat files that will probably never be needed.